# Column Family, Super Column Family, Super Column in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, hbase, datastax-enterprise

I Would like to have a clarification. I have the following hierarchy -

```
Person: {
    personal_details:{
        name:aa
        age:aaa
        ddress:aa
    }
    official_details:{
        employeeid:aa
        cubicle_number:aa
    }
}
```

I would like to represent Person in a Cassandra database. I would like each person to be queried by his **SSN** (not included in the above hierarchy).

If it were a **HBase schema**, I would call **Person** as my table. I would have **SSN** as my row key and **personal_details** as well as **official_details** as column families and **name,age,address,employeeid & cubicle_number** as columns. What is the cassandra nomenclature for these hierarchies and what could be the possible creation queries for this hierarchy in cassandra?

Comment: Even in HBase I would probably not make these two column families. column families are useful when you have a lot of columns and completely different access patterns for the families. In this case I'd just add all as columns personal_age,official_id etc.

Comment: @ArnonRotem-Gal-Oz, I just posted an example for ease of understanding. Din mean to create one such schema in cassandra or in hbase. :) Just wanted to communicate my requirement via a small exampple.

Answer (score 3):

Check the [DataStax documentation on Anatomy of a table](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.2/ddl/table).

In this case, creating the data structure you are looking for in Cassandra, the [CQL](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html) would be very similar to SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE people 
(
  ssn text PRIMARY KEY,
  name text,
  age int,
  address text,
  employeeid int,
  cubicle_number int
);
```

About super columns on Cassandra, it is now [not recommended](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.2/cluster_architecture/anti_patterns#super-columns).

Comment: Intention was not to create one such table structure. Just needed to know the script for creating such an hierarchy. Thanks any way for the help.